# Name of a Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Here is the problem description:

I have an object that represents a unit of work (Uploading a large amount of data to a server). The objects should be processed (Uploaded) in a FIFO sequence (Queue) one at a time. Once an object is done being processed it needs to signal to the next object in line that it needs to start.

There are some other edge cases / considerations. First, if the Queue is empty and an object is inserted it needs to start processing immediately. Second, the whole Queue needs to persists and be able to recover from program termination were it left off.

Any ideas how to model this solution? I have an app that has a solution but it's kind of hairy and not very concise. Looking for something eloquent.

Comment: I am afraid you are mixing different levels of abstraction here. You can't think on algorithm and implementation at the same time. Or you can, but it confuses the situation a lot. So please either write your question for a specific platform to discuss the concrete implementation, or remove the implementation specific parts to discuss just the algorithm.

Comment: @AlKepp Thanks for the feedback. I'm interested in the algorithm not the implementation. I need a little help identifying the application specific pieces of my question. Could you point them out? Is it the fact that I say I have a working implementation somewhere or the fact that I require persistence which would be very application specific? Or both? Thank you.

Comment: At first glance this is a Producer/Consumer problem, where the consumer is the  "processor" - it is busy until the work object is done being processed.  That pattern is already designed to handle your first edge case.  The second can be handled with a persistent FIFO, maybe along with a way to checkpoint partial processing in the consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AShelly mentioned, what you describe is a [Producer-Consumer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem, where the typical underlying data structure is a Queue.

More specifically, you have a process that generates data to uploaded to the server. That process is the Producer. Another process is storing these data to the server, meaning that this process is the Consumer.

The tricky part is is to synchronize these two processes, which is usually achieved using semaphores.

So far, this answer covers your completely, but the second edge case, which asks for a non-ephemeral data structure.

One approach would be to create a [persistent Queue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), since that would already match the typical data structure used in the Producer-Consumer problem.

Caveeat: What happens to an object when the program terminates as it is processed? It starts over, or somehow you continue exactly where you left off? You could leave this for later, and make your personal choice along the way.

Comment: &plus;1 for taking the time to make what I said into a complete answer :)

Comment: @AShelly best thing to do while waiting in the airport, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First,  You need more than one data structures here.  1. event handling ( where processor and helper talk each other ) with Queue 2. Persistent data structure ( there is a plenty of info available please look into wiki).

Second,  How do you want process the signal ? is it based on any priority or just FIFO ?

Third, If you are developing an android app there are already API's available.  I am not sure which platform you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If object has to be persistent, doing queue on file with mmap is one possible practical solution. Either two threads or two processes can work with one putting object in queue and next to upload in server. IPC like queue, pipe or fifo can be maintained between them. On system reboot, this IPC can be restored from mmap file. If persistent queue IPC is available, that is also a good solution. It depends on aspects like limitations on queue or how big is object.